# Problem with drawing piecewise function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the following piecewise function:

[image]

I used the following codes:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={
        func(\x)= (\x<-0.5) * (0)  +
        and(\x>=-0.5, \x<=0.5) * (1)     +
        (\x>0.5) * (0);
    }
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
        ymin=-0.25, ymax=1.25, ylabel=$y$,
        xmin=-1, xmax=1, xlabel=$x$,
        ]
        \addplot[domain=-1:1]{func(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But the output is not the same as the above plot:

[image]

Comment: This is expected --- you are joining each calculated point with the *following* one! try `\addplot coordinates{(-1,0) (-0.5,0) (-0.5,1) (0.5,1) (0.5,0) (1,0)}:` (or something like that)

Comment: Or `\addplot[domain=-1:=0.5] 0; \addplot[domain=-0.5:0.5] 1; addplot[domain=0.5:1] 0;` which is more correct (there are no vertical lines in the function!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By use of the `const plot` pgfplots option:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={func(\x) = (\x<-0.5)*(0) +
                             and 
                             (\x>=-0.5, \x<=0.5)*(1) +
                             (\x>0.5)*(0);}
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    ymin=-0.25, ymax=1.25, ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-1, xmax=1, xlabel=$x$,
    const plot,
    every axis plot post/.append style={thick},
            ]
        \addplot[domain=-1:1]{func(x)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
As you can se with your function declaration pulse is shifted for one sample to right. This you can corecte  on two ways:

- use @Rmano suggestion and draw your pulse by help of coordinates
- correct definition of your function:

```
declare function={func(\x) = (\x<-0.5)*(0) +
                             and
                             (\x>-0.51, \x<0.49)*(1) +  % <--- 
                             (\x>0.5)*(0);}
```

its effect using `\addplot +[domain=-1:1]{func(x)};`, whis show samples marks is:

[image]

Comment: Yep, better than my suggestion, +1

Comment: The vertical lines should intersect x-axis at exactly 0.5 and -0.5 but they have a distance of about 0.25!

Comment: @Moreza7, you are right. For exactly you need to use Rmano comment, approximate you can with increase number of samples or by change your function declaration (see addendum in answer).